# Delphi calling a DLL function

Tags: c#, delphi

I am having issues calling a function from a dll, I've declared the function as follows :

```
Function LicenseIsActive(): boolean;
StdCall; external 'VaultManagerTest.dll';
```

I've attempted changing the calling convention method with no success.

The function within the dll :

```
public bool LicenseIsActive() 
 {
  return License.Active;             
}
```

The Error Message when running the debugger :

[image]

Comment: How is the DLL compiled?  Is it 32 bit / 64 bit?  Is the calling app 32 or 64 bit?  I've seen that exception when there's a mismatch.

Comment: An exported C++ function with a `bool` return type is broken anyway, since `bool` is a C++ type that's only known to the C++ compiler that built the DLL.

Comment: It looks like a method, not a regular function. In C++ you don't use the public keyword for functions.

Comment: This question is tagged as C++, but I don't see any C++ in the question.  This looks like a DLL created with Delphi, and being called by Delphi.

Comment: @mirtheil I thought this as well, They are now both compiled for 64bit but still no luck

Comment: `public bool funcname` - is it valid C++ signature of regular function???

Comment: Hmmm, I did not look correctly. But is this really C++, or mighty it be a C# assembly? As it is valid C# code.

Comment: try `function LicenseIsActive(): BOOL; StdCall;`

Comment: If what @KenBourassa suggests works, it's probably because [the default calling convention in Windows 64 bit went from `stdcall` to `fastcall`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @R.Hoek Yes sorry it is C#, I will update the tags.

Comment: @GolezTrol 

I've tried both with no luck. The error only occurs once I attempt to call the function it compiles and runs with no errors if I don't call the LicenseIsActive() function.

Comment: @MrClear OK knowing this, I’m sorry to tell that you cannot use a .NET assembly like a regular dll. Using a .NET assembly requires a lot more... Please search SO first on how to use a .NET assembly from a regular Win32/64 Delphi application.

Comment: @R.Hoek Thanks, I'll do some more research on the topic.

Comment: @GolezTrol, that was my bad.  I thought it was C++... and C++'s bool <> Delphi's boolean.

Comment: Take a look at this SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/24345626/2339326

Answer (score -2):

You can't call the function directly (for the reasons explained in the comments), but here's a simple workaround that doesn't use a COM interface.

Write a C# executable that returns the boolean through the exit code, something like this:

```
using VaultManagerTest;

public class Test
{
   public static int Main()
   {
      return License.Active ? 1 : 0;
   }
}
```

In Delphi, start the executable, wait for it to finish and check its exit code.